# href a action/controller desde un anchor de html por fuera de la web (Mail)

Tags: html, c#, mvc, asp

Escenario: ASP MVC sin EF.

Tengo el RegistroController el cual ejecuta el alta de un usuario en la base de datos. Una vez realizado esto, tengo que enviar un mail con un "confirmar registro" que va a activar al usuario.
Para activar al usuario tengo que llamar a una acción de este mismo controlador, pero desde un link que le envío al usuario por mail. El problema que tengo es que cuando hago click en este href, la web queda cargando indefinidamente y no tengo respuesta, es decir, nunca se ingresa al action de este controller (Esto lo sé porque puse un punto de interrupción en el action y nunca se llega a este).

De esta manera obtengo el link de la web completo con el llamado al controller/Action + ciertos parámetros:

```
string activateURL = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + Url.Action("activateUser", "Registro", new { user = model.utilHash });
```

que genera el siguiente link:

```
localhost:44397/Registro/activateUser?user=05B081ACC52451BA1018DE74A4A0122B
```

Y armo el html completo del mail agregando este link a un href:

```
...<a href=\"" + "http://" + activateURL + "\" style=\"dis...
```

El anchor html resultante, que es el que llega en el mail es el siguiente:

```
<a href="http://localhost:44397/Registro/activateUser?user=D645795057DBCAE14F68D3A3DDCCC2F0" style="display:inline-block;background:#959292;color:#020000;font-family:Ubuntu,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;line-height:100%;Margin:0;text-decoration:none;text-transform:none;padding:14px 70px 13px 70px;border-radius:5px" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://localhost:44397/Registro/activateUser?user%3DD645795057DBCAE14F68D3A3DDCCC2F0&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1583532208657000&amp;usg=AFQjCNErL9aARChcyHOYBjGt1PH2m7JNpg">Completar registro</a>
```

En mi solución, y dentro del RegistroController la acción es la siguiente:

```
    public ActionResult activateUser(string userID)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Configuré la ruta:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ActivateAccount",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Registro", action = "activateUser", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: ¿Has visto cómo se genera ese HTML con el link?

Comment: Hola @fredyfx, edité mi respuesta y agregué el anchor resultante obtenido directamente desde el mail, igualmente es generado de manera correcta, ya que si no me redirigiría a otra web.

Comment: `http://localhost:44397/Registro/activateUser?user=D645795057DBCAE14F68D3A3DDCCC2F0` eso llamará a tu localhost... Y si tu proyecto está detenido... pues, no funcionará.

Comment: @fredyfx eso es lógico. En ningún momento comenté que se detuviera el proyecto. Todo lo probé en la misma sesión de debug, en donde tengo el aplicativo corriendo.

Comment: data-saferedirecturl sigo sin entender de dónde salió eso.

Comment: @fredyfx es un tag que agrega gmail a los anchor de html, entiendo en mails de formato html, por un tema de protección, el cual desconozco. Igualmente ese no es el problema, ya que ingresando directamente a la URL "localhost:44397/Registro/activateUser?user=05B081ACC52451BA1018DE74A4A0122B" el problema es el mismo. Tal vez entiendas mejor el problema si te lo comento como, al querer acceder a un action de un controller, mediante la url directa, enviandole un parámetro se da el problema que comento anteriormente.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega los detalles de tu controlador

Comment: @fredyfx editada.

Comment: ese `userID` no encaja con el `user=`, en la configuración de tus rutas, ¿has definido ese parámetro? Considera que by default está "ID" solamente. Me parece que estás iniciando con ASP net MVC, hice este workshop con varias cosas https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY que considero elementales de conocer. Espero te sea de utilidad

Comment: Una duda el problema es cuando le das click al link desde el correo ni funciona. Ahora si copia ese link cargas el navegador web y pegas el link tampoco funciona? Por otro lado, existe  el archivo ```activateUser.cshtml``` en el directorio correcto?.

Comment: Hola  @JuanCarlosGuibovich. El link no funciona ni abriendolo desde el anchor html del correo ni tampoco copiando el link en el navegador. La vista existe, y no sería problema que no existiera ya que me tiraría un 404 ya que al controlador entraría.

Comment: Si fue una pregunta medio tonta pero aveces el problema esta en lo más obvio. Para seguir analizando dime: eso ocurre únicamente con esa página?, es decir, si pegas el localhost:44397/ te responde con el default? Y si cargas la página sin ningún parametro ¿responde? A las finales quisiera saber en qué situaciones si responde el server (por ejemplo colocando el link de otra página en el mensaje de correo)?? Estas ejecutando IIExpress?

Comment: Hola @JuanCarlosGuibovich, ninguna pregunta es tonta si es fundamentada. Al acceder al root de mi web (http://localhost:44397/) no tengo problemas, incluso a otros controllers, como por ejemplo https://localhost:44397/Registro, ahora bien, entrando por http://localhost:44397/Registro/activateUser o por http://localhost:44397/Registro/activateUser?user=4DB7E66A742EB523FA871F9C22433483 el comportamiento es el indicado, nunca se llega al action del controller y la web queda cargando indefinidamente. Sobre el iis exacto, es el express que se ejecuta al buildear y ejecutar el proyecto en VStudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de mucho tiempo y con ayuda de la respuesta de @Juxant me di cuenta que la url es httpS, aunque el navegador y las configuraciones enmascaran y se visualice como http.
Una vez corriendo la web por el iis express verifiqué que la dirección real es con https:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que armando la URL como https resolvió el problema:

```
<a href=\"" + "https://" + activateURL + "\" style=\"display:inline-block;backgro
```

Edit:
Ampliando el tema, es cuando creas la web por primera vez se instala un certificado local que hace a esta web httpS. Cuando la hosteas, este certificado no es válido, ni se hostea, con lo cual la web deja de ser httpS para ser http.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que le agregas http a la URL, ¿estás seguro que es http, y no https? ¿Probaste accediendo al endpoint con [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)?

De todas maneras, configurando el endpoint así:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("activateUser/{userID}")]
public ActionResult activateUser(string userID)
{
    return View();
}
```

Y armando la URL de esta forma, debería funcionar.

```
http://localhost:44397/Registro/activateUser/D645795057DBCAE14F68D3A3DDCCC2F0
```

Comment: Hola @Juxant, gracias por la respuesta y disculpame la demora.
Respecto a http/s, estoy seguro que es http, no tengo certificados para https, a su vez, igualmente probé con https y el problema es el mismo.
Cambié el controller al que me comentás e intente incluso con la URL que comentás y el problema es el mismo, la web nunca carga y nunca se llega al action de este controller.

Soy un poco novato con asp mvc, debería también agregar una ruta en especial en el RouteConfig?